# I am trying to setup a a reverse proxy with SSL and Apache2

Tags: apache2, proxy, ssl, certificates

I have installed an SSL certificate from No ip. When I try and restart Apache2, I receive this error:

> AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for reverse-proxy.internal.cloudapp.net:443

I have looked through the Apache config files, but I can't find anything referencing `reverse-proxy.internal.clouadapp.net:443`. Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: How would you go about doing that